# Two kinds of of subgroups of a dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

[image]

How do we show that there are two kinds of subgroups of a dihedral group or where can I find a proof of that?

Comment: Did you just edit this and replace the text with an image? I could've sworn I saw text when I clicked on this in the page listing all the questions, but now it's gone : S

Comment: Anyhow, to answer your question… Any subgroup either contains a reflection (an element of the form $a^r x$) or not. If it does not, then it is the first kind (that is, it is a subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$). So consider the case where it contains some $a^r x$ and show that it is of the form $\langle a^d, a^r x \rangle$.

Comment: Hint for that part: Let $H$ be a subgroup containing a reflection $a^r x$ and let $d$ be the least non-negative integer such that $a^d \in H$. What if $d = 0$? What if $d \ne 0$?